# Getting subset of MATLAB vector

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have got a vector in MATLAB that represents function values. I am plotting these, but want to highlight the ones that are in a specific range. In particular I am interested in all points with function value close to, but less than 'v'. I.e. for a value 'x', I want to highlight this point if

```
abs( x - v ) < epsilon && x < v
```

If I want to select all the points 'x' such that

```
abs( x - v) < epsilon
```

what I have got to work is (I am not sure if this is good coding practice or not)

```
inds = (abs( xs - v ) < epsilon ) ;
```

and then plot the xs against my ys in axes a

```
plot( a, ys(inds), xs(inds), 'ks ' ) ;
```

This approach is no longer working if I try and do

```
inds = (abs( xs - v) < epsilon && xs < v ) ;
```

In this case I am getting the following error, no matter how I arrange the brackets:

'Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.'

I guess I have two questions

1.) Why does the approach not work if I try and use the logical &&? As far as I can see I am using expressions that can be converted to logical scalar values

2.) Is this a good way to select a subset of points in MATLAB?

Thanks,
Keeran

Comment: To the "why" question: && does short-circuit evaluation ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation ), while & does not.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Good bit of information, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `&&` is only for *scalar* values. You have vectors, not scalars, so you have to use `&` instead:

```
inds = ( abs(xs-v) < epsilon & xs < v );
```

Other than that yes, it is the right way to select a subset of points.

For reference, note that `&` also works for scalars. The reason to have `&&` is that it is potentially faster for scalars (see [`doc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html)).

Comment: +1 Magic. Works like a charm. Feel kinda silly I didn't try this before :)